# Can't download the whole sqlite file from icloud

Tags: file, sqlite, icloud

Hi, I have already uploaded a sqlite3 file to icloud. Now I want to download this file to my APP's Document folder. After I pressed the download button, it will show the success information. But in fact, there is no sqlite file in the documents folder or maybe the file is broken. Could someone help me?

```
-(IBAction)downloadPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(![self downloadFileIfNotAvailable:self.icloudURL])
    {
        [self displayAlert:@"Warning!!" withmessage:@"failed to restore"];
    }else{
        [self displayAlert:@"Congratulations" withmessage:@"restore sccuessfully"];
    }
}

-(BOOL)downloadFileIfNotAvailable:(NSURL *)file
{
    NSNumber*  isIniCloud = nil;
    NSError* err;
    if ([file getResourceValue:&isIniCloud forKey:NSURLIsUbiquitousItemKey error:nil]) {
        // If the item is in iCloud, see if it is downloaded.
        if ([isIniCloud boolValue]) {
            NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            if([fm removeItemAtPath:self.filePath error:&err])
            {
                if (![fm startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:file error:nil]) {
                    return NO;
                }else{
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Who knows the reason? I really need your help